# Keeping timestamps accurate in chat system - using timeago jQuery plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm creating a web-based chat/messaging system. Since the chats can be saved, each message of a chat and the time in which each message was sent are stored on the server in a mysql database. Timestamps are stored in mysql DATETIME format in UTC time and the timestamps are generated on the server.

As messages and their accompanying timestamps are retrieved from the server, I'm using the [jQuery timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) and formatting the timestamps to display in the form "1 minute ago", "3 days ago", and so on.

The problem with this is that the "timeago" time is calculated relative to the time of the user's machine. For example, say you receive a message that was actually sent only 2 seconds ago. If your machine's time is three minutes fast relative to the server's time, then the time for this message displays as "3 minutes ago".

Any ideas for strategies that will always present the accurate time to the user?

Comment: can you calculate the delta between user time and server time, then add it up to the result

Comment: that'll do it. probably i'll take this route if no other bulbs flash. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly are you sure you want such a precise time synchronization for a chat system? If someone's clock is ahead and behind, its his/her problem, not yours.

Anyway you could send across the difference to the user. The time-delta can be used to create a timestamp from the current time, and put it in the title attribute.

A simpler way would be to just send a message saying "This message was sent 'just now'" and the title attribute is constructed accordingly.

Comment: yes, if it's possible, i want 100% precision. getting the client/server time delta will do it. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the source code. See line 146 in https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/jquery.timeago.js. Make it optionally work with a user specified "now" that overrides new Date(). Then have the server tell the client what "now" is in server time.

Alternatively, there's a way to do it without modifying timeago's source:

Have the server tell the client what is its current time, then calculate the difference between that and the client's time:

```
var timeDelta = serverNow - clientNow
```

Then, add timeDelta to each message's time before passing it to timeago.

Comment: thanks meetamit. this would work for messages sent/received in an active chat session, but not when opening an existing chat and downloading the saved messages and their corresponding timestamps.